# Facebook LIKE Button Using Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a website in which there are more than three **Facebook Page Like Button**. Once user click on the button. First, I need to authenticate the user and then like the respective page. However User authentication is working fine now I need to Like a page. I am following the ***[Facebook Like Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.6/object/likes)***. But I am getting confused with ***{object-id}*** metioned in the documentation. What is this ***object-id*** and How do I get this ?

**Like** Page Code :

```
session_start();
require_once 'autoload.php';
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'App_ID','App_Secret' );

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/fb/like.php' );
try {

    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();

} catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // Facebook returns an error
} catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // validation fails or other local issues
}

if ( isset( $session ) ) {
    // Get Basic Userinfo
    $getUserInfoObj = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/me' );
    $getUserInfoProcess = $getUserInfoObj->execute();
    $getUserInforesult = $getUserInfoProcess->getGraphObject();
    $id = $getUserInforesult->getProperty('id');

    // Once Use Logged In Like the respective page
    // Like page code


    echo '<pre>';print_r($getUserInforesult);exit;
    //header("Location: index.php");
} else {
    $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
    header("Location: ".$loginUrl);
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure you can't like pages using the API

Comment: Hello @WizKid, Thank you. Can you please click on the documentation link as mentioned above and please read the ***Publishing*** section. What they want to say?

Comment: If you don't believe me then just test it and prove me wrong.

Comment: @WizKid, I am not proving anything. I just want to know If it's not possible then why they added this section ? Is it for something different mean ? Or I am on a wrong track?

Comment: You can like other stuff I believe. But not pages. But I could be wrong

Comment: Nope, that’s totally correct. The _only_ way to like Facebook Pages is via the official Like button. Posts/comments can be liked via API, and external Open Graph objects can have the `og.likes` action published on them - but for Pages it is the Like button only. (Most likely due to the fact that it would just have too much abuse potential otherwise.)

Answer (score 0):

Object Id is your page, comment, post even photo id that want to make liked.

For example stackoverflow facebook page link is,
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Stack-Overflow/105665906133609?fref=ts

so the object_id is 105665906133609

Comment: Thanks, @Jregon. I was thinking its page id. It would be great if you provide some sample code.

Comment: This api don't let you like pages, and this documention shows you who likes your page.